# How can i create this regex about this condition

Tags: c#, regex, expression

I want to do this via regex:
sample:
**father** goes visit his grandfather and and his **father** today.

how do i select bold two father via regular expression? thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure why you need regular expressions for this, since you can "select" the string you want simply by doing:

```
String myStr = "father";
```

Alternatively, if you need to replace the substring in the string, you can just do the following:

```
String myStr = "father goes visit his grandfather and and his father today."
myStr = myStr.Replace(" father ", " someOtherString ");
```

But, if you *really* want to use RegEx, you can get a `MatchCollection` by doing:

```
String myStr = "father goes visit his grandfather and and his father today."
Regex.Mathces(myStr, "\bfather\b");
```

It's not a very interesting regex because it is simply an unambiguous string literal.

Answer (score 1):

try this

```
var matchs=Regex.matches("father goes visit his grandfather and and his father today.",@"\bfather\b");
```

Answer (score 1):

```
var matchCollection = Regex.Matches("father goes visit his grandfather and and his father today.", "\bfather\b");

foreach (Match m in matchCollection)
{
     // Process your code for each match
}
```